# Any other way to setValue of array values into individual columns in google sheet without using loop with Javascript/GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've learnt earlier to use "for" loop to print each array value into it's individual column in the same row

```
myArrayval=["minor","major","large","huge","enourmous","big","tiny"];

 for(i=0;i<myArrayval.length;i++){
    sheet.getRange(lastrow,i+19).setValue(myArrayval[i]);
  }
```

Could there be another way without looping? My objective is to get the output as fast as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sheet.getRange(lastrow,1,1,myArrayval.length).setValues([myArrayval]);
```

[Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Great! Your answer works just as I needed! Thanks a lot, @Cooper.